PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? what to do
I'm trying to resolve this error even after installing poppler even after giving it,s path in C drive i'm having trouble in resolving it. what to do?
please see this error (image attach )
i tired everthing mentioned on this stack page .(How to install Poppler on Windows?
